# Solutions for Using the Computer to Write Equations

Tags: calculus, math-software

What software solutions are available to express math problems? I want to be able to quickly type complex equations (especially with common notations in Calculus) for printing and online sharing.

Comment: LaTeX is always a good option.  Its free, its powerful, and it does more than just math.  There is quite a steep learning curve, though.  Search the web for examples of other people's documents, then modify those to fit your needs.  Its essentially like writing code, but you may find that much better than MS Word's WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: From the [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq): (...) some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: (...) Typesetting equations. Therefore I voted to close.

Answer (score 6):

Tex is the most useful software for scientific and mathematical writing. See for example, http://www.math.jmu.edu/~arnoldea/latex_setup_and_tutorial.htm

You will have to learn the syntax, but you will never regret learning Tex, that is unless you only learn it to use it once. There are vast amounts of resources online to help you in learning this software.